# Angular 2 Asp.net core Loading page without a shared layout

Tags: asp.net-core, angular2-template

I would like to know how to have a login page while using angular 2 with asp.net core, that does not uses the shared layout and does not load other components in it.

For example my app.component.html looks like this:

```
<nav-menu></nav-menu>

<top-nav></top-nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And I would like to be able to have a login page that does not include the nav-menu and top-nav.

In theory the login page would be the default page.

I am not understanding how this is possible with Angular 2.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this issue by using 2 main components, one for login and other for navigation.

Inside the navigation component I added all the other components as children.

If anyone wants help on this I can explain it better, just a leave a comment.

Comment: I am also having this problem. Can you explain it